# Why this JavaScript code combining the elements of array instead of adding the elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, sum, concatenation

```js
var kaul= new Array(); //New Array
var sum=0, vv;
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) //loop**strong text**
{
kaul[i]=prompt("Enter number");
vv=kaul[i];
sum+=vv;
}
alert(sum);
```

This code is concatenating the elements of array "kaul" instead of adding the elements. Need Help!

Comment: what's in your array?

Comment: Convert kaul[i]  to a number, it's treating the prompt result as a string.

Comment: Because `Prompt` returns a string. Try `sum+=parseInt(vv);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from *prompt* is a string - you need to parse it to a `Number` - use `sum += +vv;`

See demo below:

```js
var kaul = new Array(); //New Array
var sum = 0,
  vv;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) //loop
{
  kaul[i] = prompt("Enter number");
  vv = kaul[i];
  sum += +vv;
}
alert(sum);
```